# Codigo do campo no atributo value do option

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tenho uma tabela `CategoriaCNH` com os seguintes campos `CodCategoriaCNH` e `Descricao`.

e tenho este trecho de código `html`:

```
<select name="categoriaCnh">
    <option value="" disabled selected>CNH</option>
        @foreach($categoriaCnh as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->CodCategoriaCNH}}">{{$cat->Descricao}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

No atributo `value` do `option` estou setando o `CodCategoriaCNH` que vem da minha tabela `CategoriaCNH`.

**A questão é:**

Levando em consideração a segurança..

É aconselhável colocar o `CodCategoriaCNH` assim diretamente no atributo `value`?

Ou o ideal seria o atributo `value` ter o valor da coluna `Descricao`, e no `back-end` eu recupero o `CodCategoriaCNH` ?

Comment: Não vejo muito problema em expor o id, ainda mais se for algo como A, AB, etc. Qual a sua preocupação especifica?

Comment: @gmsantos, minha preocupação é, expondo o Id estarei correndo algum risco de segurança? se é possivel ter falhas de segurança expondo o Id..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Por um lado,**

Penso ser mais seguro da forma atual, como representada no seu código de amostra [*sample*], já que somente o resultado da consulta está sendo mostrado.

Se você tentar recuperar o valor depois, quando o formulário for submetido, aí sim **poderá** ter problemas de segurança, já que os usuários podem passar novos valores no *select* para serem consultados depois.

A *query* que é atualmente

```
select CodCategoriaCNH from Table group by CodCategoriaCNH
```

ficaria

```
select Descricao from Table group by Descricao
```

para então ser submetida ao banco back end novamente, onde você pegaria a descrição e faria:

```
select top (1) CodCategoriaCNH from Table where Descricao = :descricao
```

Como pode  perceber na última *query*, Laravel usa [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) para os [funções básicas de banco de dados](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/seam/html/crud_database_application.html), então, todas as precauções de segurança são adotas nas consultas, [sem qualquer problema relatado até o momento](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1cp48m/is_laravel_really_all_that_and_a_bag_of_chips/).

**Por outro lado,**

Sei que o Laravel tem as implementações de segurança e boas práticas necessárias para criar aplicações robustas e seguras, então a forma como se usa cabe a quem está desenvolvendo, sendo recomendado seguir a [documentação do framework](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/introduction), além do mais, fazer uma segunda consulta ao banco de dados seria mais cansativo e trabalhoso tanto para o desenvolvedor, (você, OP!) quanto para o banco de dados (memória e tempo de processamento).

Mas este é somente um dos pontos a serem considerados, não sendo, portanto, esta "resposta" exaustiva ou mesmo conclusiva.